# Add object with id autogenerated in a Set results in only adding one element by using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence

I want to create more objects and add them to a set. The hashcode and equals methods are dependent on id ( I can't change that ).

To start with, each object has id=0 and when trying to add to the set will result in adding only the first object.

If I am using session.save(object) after each creation, the set will contain all elements.

The problem is that the id isn't created.

Do you have any solution for this? Saving each time I create an object is not easy because to do this I need to change a lot of code.

I added equals and hashcode from base class
Thank you

```
public class Employee extend HibernateEntity{

    public Employee(String name){
        em_name = name;
    }
}



//doesn't work because id=0 for both, it will add only the first one
Set set = new HashSet<Employee>();
set.add(Employee("lala"));
set.add(Employee("baba"));


works because save will provide a generated id and the object will not be the same
Set set = new HashSet<Employee>();
Employee em1 = Employee("lala");
session.save(em1);
set.add(em1);

Employee em2 = Employee("baba");
session.save(em2);
set.add(em2);
```

Equals and hashcode from base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class HibernateEntity extends HibernateObject implements Cloneable {

/* Primary key */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-generator")
protected long id;


public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = PRIME * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

@Override
public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof HibernateEntity)) {
        return false;
    }

    obj = HibernateHelper.getRealObject(obj);
    Object thisImpl = HibernateHelper.getRealObject(this);

    if (thisImpl.getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    // It's now safe to cast object
    final HibernateEntity other = (HibernateEntity) obj;
    final HibernateEntity thisHibernteImpl = (HibernateEntity) thisImpl;
    if (thisHibernteImpl.id != other.id) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Please post a minimal, complete code example.

Comment: I edit it. Thank you

Comment: Lots of issues here. (1) Did you override `equals`? Generally don't for entities. (2) Use nullable types for IDs (`Long`). (3) Don't call the generator manually; let Hibernate do that.

Comment: Yes, equals and hashcode are overrided, I can't change that.  Why I should use nullable types? Would it make a change in the behaviour? I don't call the generator manually

Comment: Adding Long as id gave me an null pointer exception so it didn't help